# UITextView takes a while to load the text into it, how to show loading icon?

Tags: ios, swift, view, loading

I have a textview with text in it. It takes a while to load the text, so how can I show a loading icon while it loads the text to it, and when it's done placing the text in the textview then delete the loading icon?

Hope to hear from you guys

Comment: as a best practice it is better to show a loader on the screen itself until all elements are loaded. If you want to achieve this then use: SVProgressHUD

Answer (score 1):

**Tested code:-**

```
//show progress activity indicator inside UITextView

extension UITextView { 
    func loadingIndicator(show: Bool) {
        if show {
            let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
            self.isEditable = false
            indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
            indicator.color = UIColor.red
            let viewHeight = self.bounds.size.height
            let viewWidth = self.bounds.size.width
            indicator.center = CGPoint(x: viewWidth/2, y: viewHeight/2)
            self.addSubview(indicator)
            indicator.startAnimating()
        } else {
            for view in self.subviews {
                if let indicator = view as? UIActivityIndicatorView {
                    indicator.stopAnimating()
                    indicator.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.isEditable = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:-**

`tvTextView.loadingIndicator(show: true/false)`

Answer (score 0):

Use UIActivityIndicator :

1. Add `UIActivityIndicator` on View
2. Set its `activityIndicator.isHidden = true`
3. Then use `activityIndeicator.hidesWhenStopped = true`
4. Set its `activityIndicator.isHidden = false`
5. And when you assigning text to TextView then use `activityIndicator.startAnimating()`
6. And when text is loaded to TextView then use
   `activityIndicator.stopAnimating()`

Hope it helps you

Comment: This isn't going to work without something extra.  After you have set the isHidden property of the activityIndicator and started it animating if you then set the text of the UITextView  the UI won't update until the text view has finished setting it's text meaning activity indictor won't actually be visible until after the delay in setting the text upon which it is then hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those simple sounding things that is actually a little tricky.

First the simple part is to add a UIActivityIndicatorView and set it up appropriately (add to the view, set to hidden initially, the hidesWhenStopped property to true, etc).

Now you would think you could just do something like this:

```
self.activityIndictor.startAnimating()
self.textView.text = self.data
self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

but that won't work because execution waits when setting the text view and doesn't update the UI so you don't see the activity indicator.

What does work is this:

```
self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    self.textView.text = self.data
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

What that does is to start the activity indicator animating and then dispatch the actual setting of the text view back onto the main thread which gives the UI a chance to update and you see the activity indicator.

Note you have to use asyncAfter with a small time delay instead of just a straight async call because that doesn't give the UI time to update.